# Why isn't my app on the list of apps to open txt file?

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver

I have an text reader app that is designed to receive intent from Android system when I click on a text file to open it.  But my app isn't on the list popped up by the system.  Below are my codes:

Manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.broadcastreceivertest1"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />

<application
android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
android:label="@string/app_name" >
<activity
android:label="@string/app_name"
android:name=".BroadcastReceiverTest1Activity" >
<intent-filter >
<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
</activity>

<receiver android:name="MyBroadcastReceiver"> 
<intent-filter> 
<action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_VIEW" /> 
<action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_EDIT" /> 
<action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_PICK" /> 
<data android:scheme="file" /> 
<data android:mimeType="*/*" /> 
<data android:pathPattern=".*\\.txt" />    
<data android:host="*" /> 
</intent-filter> 
</receiver> 

</application>

</manifest>
```

My extended BroadcastReceiver

```
public final class MyBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
private String TAG = "MyBroadcastReceiver";

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
Intent i = new Intent(context, BroadcastReceiverTest1Activity.class);
i.putExtra("URI", intent.getData());
context.startActivity(i);
Log.d(TAG, "Leaving onReceived...");
}
}
```

My activity to be opened by the broadcast receiver

```
public class BroadcastReceiverTest1Activity extends Activity {

private String uri ="";
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.main);
final Intent intent = getIntent();

final String action = intent.getAction();

if(Intent.ACTION_VIEW.equals(action)){
uri = intent.getStringExtra("URI");
TextView textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
textView.setText(uri);

}

}
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You need to associate your app with file extension. To do so, add these two line within intent filter and u'r good to go

```
<data android:scheme="file" />
<data android:mimeType="*/*"/>
<data android:pathPattern=".*\\.pdf" />
```

And your manifest would be look like this

```
<activity name="com.your.activity">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <data android:scheme="file" />
        <data android:mimeType="*/*" />
        <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.txt" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

`<data android:scheme="file" />` => this define that the file must be local, not from http or else

`<data android:mimeType="*/*" />` => match any mime type

`<data android:pathPattern=".*\\.txt" />` => this is where you specify what extension you want to match

Hope this help

Comment: I just want my app to be on the list of opening text files, but now my app is on the list for every type of files.  I did have <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.txt" /> , but I wonder if I should specify mimeType.  What should I do to restrict my app to only appearing on list of opening text files?

Comment: change mime type to 
`<data android:mimeType="text/plain" />`

Comment: Where do I put this? I tried [this](https://pastebin.com/HiqWvkFw) and [this](https://pastebin.com/yWYKEH7x) but none of them worked.

Answer (score 8):

elaborating on HERO's pseudo code, this effectively works:

change the `<manifest>` like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.broadcastreceivertest1"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="9" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:name=".BroadcastReceiverTest1Activity" >
            <intent-filter >

                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data android:scheme="file" />
                <data android:mimeType="*/*" />
                <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.txt" />
            </intent-filter> 
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

**drop your broadcast receiver**, because it is unnecessary.

change your BroadcastReceiverTest1Activity class (it does **NOT need to be your MAIN activity**, see BONUS below):

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.TextView;
public class BroadcastReceiverTest1Activity extends Activity {
    private String TAG = "TagOpenTxt";
    private String uri ="";
    private Uri uri2;
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        final Intent intent = getIntent();  
        final String action = intent.getAction();

        if(Intent.ACTION_VIEW.equals(action)){
            //uri = intent.getStringExtra("URI");
            uri2 = intent.getData();
            uri = uri2.getEncodedPath() + "  complete: " + uri2.toString();
            TextView textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
            textView.setText(uri);
            // now you call whatever function your app uses 
            // to consume the txt file whose location you now know 
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, "intent was something else: "+action);
        }
    }
}
```

you have effectively created an **intent listener for TXT files**, which will call your app IF the user decides to use it (unless the user has previously associated file type TXT to another app...)

your app does **NOT need to be active** to catch intents.  once installed, the system recognizes it as one of the "goto apps" for the particular mime types and/or extensions (less easy than associating by mime type) you chose.

BONUS: you can have a separate MAIN activity and when your BroadcastReceiver is called, it will **execute within the same sandbox** as your application, without impacting it (you will have to implement that in your MAIN activity's `onResume` method).

you can **read the text data** into **static variable(s) [sloppy]** OR you can place it in a **SQLite** db, which is **permanent AND safe**, regardless of app and/or phone shutting down, for example.

you could have the activity selfterminating and never even firing up a layout/window - which is sort of weird in case your user wants some kind of confirmation that the txt file was correctly and completely consumed by app.

Answer (score 4):

You have to register an ACTIVITY not a broadcast receiver with the filter attributes.

Answer (score 0):

The `text/plain` Mime type works well on all Android devices except Samsung. I don't know why this is so, but the problem appears to be specific to their phones. You need to add the `application/txt` mime type to AndroidManifest to target Samsung phones as well.