# Mime type for .txt files?

Tags: android, text-files, share, mime-types

I´m trying to share a `.txt` file with share intent. If I set "text/plain" as mime type, it reads the content like text not like text file, then the options given in the share menu are Whatsapp, Line, etc..

Does anybody know how to configure the share intent so that the share options are only the programs that are able to send a `.txt` file (Gmail, Dropbox, etc.. but not Whatsapp..)? Thanks

Answer (score 178, accepted):

You can try the specific mime:

```
text/plain
```

or, the more general text mime:

```
text/*
```

Answer (score 0):

[simple and complete example code (less than 50 lines)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15555455/1166727) for app that android will present to the user along with menu list of compatible apps (polaris, browser, etc) when opening a TXT file.

disclaimer: in case user hasnt previously determined a default app

note; TXT may be changed, you can customize your extensions, if you generate the files that your app consumes.