# Open a file with my android App

Tags: android, android-intent, android-file

I'm developing an app, and I need the user to be able to open my app for example when an attached file is clicked from the gmail app, or from the downloads folder, or from the "File Explorer".

I've already been googling a lot and even found some questions here in SO, but I can't make this work.

This is how my Manifest.xml file looks like:

```
<receiver android:name="MySMS2CloudReceiver"> 
<intent-filter> 
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_VIEW" /> 
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_EDIT" /> 
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_PICK" /> 
    <data android:scheme="http" /> 
    <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.xml" />    
    <data android:host="*" /> 
    <data android:mimeType="application/rss+xml" />
    <data android:mimeType="application/atom+xml" />
    <data android:mimeType="application/xml" />
    <data android:mimeType="text/xml" />
</intent-filter>    
</receiver>
```

My broadcast receiver:

```
public class MySMS2CloudReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.d("MySMS2CloudReceiver", "Leaving onReceived...");
    }
}
```

But right now, when I click an attached file from an email in the pop up with the title "Complete Action Using" my app is not even listed there...

Any idea of what maybe happening?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Personally, I haven't done this before, but have you tried this solution?

[Why isn't my app on the list of apps to open txt file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11152838/why-isnt-my-app-on-the-list-of-apps-to-open-txt-file)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts
of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become
invalid if the linked page changes. If you think this question is a duplicate, you can also vote to close it as a duplicate.