# Android OpenWith Dialog for all files

Tags: java, android, android-listview

I'm creating an application to view java, c, and text files. I want my app to appear in openwith dialog (but currently (the file format is not supported) toast message gets displayed when I click on the file.  Please help me out in this.

Comment: You need to give use some more information... What have you tried, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find a good tutorial here:
http://richardleggett.co.uk/blog/2013/01/26/registering_for_file_types_in_android/
or [Why isn't my app on the list of apps to open txt file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11152838/why-isnt-my-app-on-the-list-of-apps-to-open-txt-file/20349826#20349826)

If this doesn't help, please post some code. :)