# How to handle home key to redirect application using intent chooser?

Tags: android

In our application we have to open pdf file through application.Our application nothing but pdfviewer. I have referred ([Why isn't my app on the list of apps to open txt file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11152838/why-isnt-my-app-on-the-list-of-apps-to-open-txt-file/20349826#20349826)) this link. It works fine for me. In case if i click on home button , and tried to open another pdf from file explorer it redirects to my application. 
Please look into this.

Thanks,
AA.

Comment: You cannot override home key in android. Android don't allow it, Check documentation for more detail.

Comment: How can i avoid this to redirect my application? i haven't used broadcast receiver.

Comment: check my answer post below.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possible solution:

Override below method in your activity.

```
@Override
public void onAttachedToWindow() {
    super.onAttachedToWindow();
    this.getWindow().setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_KEYGUARD);           
}
```

After overriding above method, now you can easily listen HOME Key press in your activity using onKeyDown() method.

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {     

    if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HOME)
    {
       //The Code Want to Perform. 
    }
});
```

Reference: http://nisha113a5.blogspot.com/