# How to avoid home key to redirect application in android

Tags: android

In my application , we are opening local pdf using below link:
([Why isn't my app on the list of apps to open txt file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11152838/why-isnt-my-app-on-the-list-of-apps-to-open-txt-file)). Its work fine for first local pdf, but if i click home key of device application goes background and i tries to open file explorer it redirects to application and onResume method gets called which shows Pdfreader activity default. I tried finishTaskOnLaunch , clearTaskOnLaunch , launchMode as singleTask , singleTop.
Please need help.

Comment: The homekey functionality cannot be manipulated..

Answer (score 1):

You cannot override the homekey. The Home button is made by android to provide a solution to the users to exit from malicious applications that could harm their devices.

As the accepted answer from this post said: [Overriding the Home button - how do I get rid of the choice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2079691/overriding-the-home-button-how-do-i-get-rid-of-the-choice)

So try to do what you want in a different way

Comment: can you please explain your answer in detail? as per given above link i have made changed in manifest and in onResume of activity , i am checking intent.getAction = Intent.ACTION_VIEW .But i dont understand why onResume is getting called forecfully if i tries to open file explorer to pick up second pdf. Even i tried onNewIntent method to set new intent but its not working

Answer (score 0):

close the file connection inside the onpause() method of your activity may fix your problem.

Comment: can you please explain your answer in detail? as per given above link i have made changed in manifest and in onResume of activity , i am checking intent.getAction = Intent.ACTION_VIEW .But i dont understand why onResume is getting called forecfully if i tries to open file explorer to pick up second pdf. Even i tried onNewIntent method to set new intent but its not working

Comment: because you currently open it as a part of your activity.use the activity flag  FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK