# Can't add my app to the list of suggested apps for image selection

Tags: android, android-intent

I want Android to suggest my app for choosing an image from gallery. But it is not included in the list of apps, not even when I try to attach a file in the Gmail app.

Here is my manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.pick_me"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.pick_me.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PICK" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: @Andrei Anischevici: I test it, nothing changed. My app isn't in the list.

Comment: A note for your future questions: You don't need to add the context at its beginning (like `Android:...`). Tags exist for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

You could try registering your app with the image/* mime type, [similarly to the answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11152838/why-isnt-my-app-on-the-list-of-apps-to-open-txt-file).

So, you'd have something like:

```
<activity name="com.your.activity">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <data android:scheme="file" />
        <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
        <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.*" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Or:

```
<intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.PICK" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.ALTERNATIVE" />
        <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
</intent-filter>
```

Comment: Also, check [this sample](http://developer.android.com/training/sharing/receive.html#update-manifest).

Comment: I have updated the answer. If still no succeeded, try setting `android:mimeType to */*` as a temporary solution, to see if your app will be suggested for any file picking actions..

Comment: Well, the "send" and "view" bit is actually unrelieved. but I test it with the mimeType "*/*", and still nothing. It should be something simple.

Comment: Did you also try adding `<category android:name="android.intent.category.ALTERNATIVE" />
                 <category android:name="android.intent.category.SELECTED_ALTERNATIVE" />` ?

Comment: I just try them, Nothing.